# RegEx for matching "01.0 to 60.0 in steps of 0.5, or 99.9"?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I'm creating an API to communicate with an industrial vacuum device.

The valid motor frequency values are as stated below, is in the form XX.X:

01.0 to 60.0 in steps of 0.5 Hz, or 99.9 Hz

I came to the following solution myself (in python):

```
import re
p = re.compile('[0-5]\d.[05]|01.0|60.0|99.9')
```

However, I can still match 00.5, which should not match.

I don't want to exclude 00.5 explicitly, and maybe I forgot some other end-case which I didn't check.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Even though the solution by Joseph Bailey works, I still think it would be better to stick to float types for such comparisons (assuming that the motor frequency is also a float)

Comment: I would love it if you could share your idea on how to verify the validity of this data using float types. I switched to str because the best way seemed to me by regex instead of multiple condition statements.

Comment: Well you need to define what format the input is in to be honest.

Comment: Actually, I wrote above and thought it was clear that the input formatting should be: XX.X  (X being any Unicode character). I code in python, so the variable type is not exactly defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `0[1-9]\.[05]` as an option and limit the other base to 1-5

```
p = re.compile('0[1-9]\.[05]|[1-5]\d\.[05]|60\.0|99\.9')
```

You also need to use `\.` instead of `.` because `.` means any character.
Finally no longer any need for the 01.0 condition

Comment: Thanks! Looks so simple and amazing.

Comment: I think you should add `^` and `$` otherwise this could also match `"abc55.5xyz"`

Comment: yeh he should, depends really what the input is of course, maybe it is 01.0hz?

I am unsure why he needs the regex but as it is more a regex expression question I will leave him to fine tune it.

Comment: I wanted it as regex because of the complexity of the problem, and CPU-wise I think this method is faster than mathematical operations and multiple 'if' statements to test for the validity of 'float' types in the required form.

Comment: OK so please accept if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The `\d` matches digits 0-9. If you don't want the value to start with `00` you could use a negative lookahead (?!00)

You might use:

```
^(?!00)[0-5]\d\.[05]|60\.0|99\.9$
```

- `^(?!00)` Start of string and assert what is directly on the right is not 00
- `[0-5]\d` Match 00 - 59
- `\.[05]|60\.0|99\.9` Match a dot and a digit 0 or 5 or 60.0 or 99.9
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rIssyt/1)

Comment: this wont match 10,20,30,40 or 50

Answer (score 0):

Since data recorded by measurement devices or by all kinds of industrial devices is usually of type `float`, I'd strongly recommend to keep the float type and avoid conversion to string. This has the advantage, that matching strings like `'"abc55.5xyz"'` is avoided and only valid floats are registered. It should also be faster than using regex with float->str conversion. You could for example use numpy to check for correct values.

First you need to create an array of correct values. You only need to do this once at the beginning of your code. No need to do it at each iteration.

```
import numpy as np
lowest_val = 1.
interm_val = 60.
stepsize = .5
highest_val = 99.9
# create the array of correct values:
correct_vals = np.empty(120)
# fill array with steps:
correct_vals[:-1] = np.linspace(lowest_val, interm_val, num=int((interm_val - lowest_val)/stepsize + 1))
correct_vals[-1] = highest_val  # add highest value
```

Now you can check for correct values with

```
motor_freq in correct_vals
```

This will return `True` when the motor frequency is within the specified values, else `False`.
If, as you added, your data is consisting of unicode chars of format `XX.X`, you will have to convert it to float for the comparison, for example with `motor_freq = float('15.5')`

Comment: Thank you, however, the data is sent by serial communication as ASCII anyways, byte by byte, so formatting it as float and then parsing or formatting back to byte form seemed to be exhausting, instead of one-liner with regex.

Comment: Oh ok. Yeah, then it may be better to use regex. However if you want to store/process the value later, then a float conversion will be better.

Comment: Let's not forget that I also have the formatting of XX.X to take care of, so for every value less than 10 decimal I will need to zero pad once, which in a float is only possible when formatting back to str

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to break it down

`(?:0[1-9]|[1-5]\d)\.[05]|60\.0|99\.9`

Expanded

```
   (?: 0 [1-9] | [1-5] \d )
   \. [05] 
|  
   60\.0
|  
   99\.9
```